# re.sub between two tags

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string and replacement text I want to subtitute:

```
original_text = '<title>Kramer vs. Kramer</title>'
replacement_text = "Kramer V Kramer"
--> '<title>Kramer V Kramer</title>'
```

How would I do this replacement via regex? So far I have:

```
re.sub(r'title>.+</title>', replacement_text, original_text)
```

However, this is removing the entire tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lookarounds.

```
>>> original_text = '<title>Kramer vs. Kramer</title>'
>>> replacement_text = "Kramer V Kramer"
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=<title>).+?(?=</title>)', replacement_text, original_text, flags=re.S)
'<title>Kramer V Kramer</title>'
```

- `(?<=<title>)` lookbehind asserts that the match must be preceeded by opening `title` tag.
- `.+?` will do a non-greedy match of one or more characters.
- `(?=</title)` asserts that the match must be followed by the closing title tag.
- `flags=re.S` allows `.` to match across lines.